# Is it possible to assign a variable as a value in a dictionary (for Python)?

Tags: python, dictionary, variables, nlp-question-answering

for variables 'a' and 'b' in dictionary 'dict1' is it possible to later call variable 'a' using its key given in 'dict1' to assign a value to it??

````
 a=""
 b=""
 dict1= {0:a,1:b}

    dict1[0] = "Hai"    #assign a value to the variable using the key

    print(a)            #later call the variable```
````

Comment: Did you try and run this?

Comment: You cannot change what a name refers to, except by direct assignment to the name. This is distinct from *mutating* the object a name refers to, but a `str` is immutable.

Comment: @Sid it didn't work.

Comment: @chepner so we can only assign directly??

Comment: Yes. `dict1[0]` and `a` are two entirely separate names for the `str`; assigning to `dict1[0]` has no more affect on the value of `a` than would `b = a; b = "Hai"`.

Answer (score 0):

No, when you do the assignment {key:value}, the value doesn't refer to the original variable, so mutating either one will not affect the other.

Comment: is there a way we can do this? or someway to get this function done

Answer (score 0):

The variable is not set automatically, what you could do is:

```
def update_dic(a,b):
   dict1={0:a, 1:b}
   return dict1

def update_vars(dict1):
   return dict1[0],dict1[1]
```

Every time you call the first function your dictionary is getting updated, and for the second time you always get a and b back.

Comment: Do you know of any way to access a set of variables by a set of keys??

Comment: I think the only way is with two functions i put the above in my answer.

Comment: This is can be used if a, b is known /given as input, but what I am looking for is where the key is given as input and to change the value of a or be according the key provided.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something similar using a class to store your variables and the indexing dictionary:

```
class Variables():
    def __init__(self):
        self.varIndex = dict()

    def __getitem__(self,index):
        return self.__dict__[self.varIndex[index]]

    def __setitem__(self,index,value):
        self.__dict__[self.varIndex[index]] = value

variables = Variables()

variables.a = 3
variables.b = 4
variables.varIndex = {0:"a",1:"b"}
variables[0] = 8
print(variables.a) # 8
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do this by using two dictionaries with the same amount of variables:

This allows to access the variable 'a' using the key '0' and then altering its value using 'dict2' and later get the value by calling 'a'.

however remember that the variables need to written as string i.e. in quotes, it doesn't work when used as a regular variable.

`````
 dict1= {0:'a',1:'b'}
 dict2={'a':'x','b':'y'}

 dict2[dict1[0]]="Hai"    #assign a value to the variable using the key

 print(dict2['a'])          #later call the variable ````
`````